# OpenCV decode JPEG returning noisy images

Tags: python, opencv, decoding

I'm trying to use the following code to apply some compression to images in memory for augmentation purposes. But then when I load it back it gives me some lossy images like these.

[image: result image]

I hovered the mouse to the noises shown by matplotlib. One of the channels always have a value of 1. The folowing code reproduces the problem.

```
  img = np.clip(cv2.resize(img,(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE)) * 255, 0, 255).astype(int) 
  r,img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img, ENCODE_PARAM)
  img = 1 - cv2.imdecode(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Comment: what you try to do with tish code? Why do you use `1 - ..` ?

Comment: I am blending numbers into random backgrounds so I can generate infinite data. Idk why but I have to use 1-... to make the image plot correct colors with matplotlib

Comment: maybe you have to do it because `cv2` keeps image as BGR instead of RGB. But it has function to convert colors `img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`

Comment: what is ENCODE_PARAM? Did you explicitly or implicitly choose very bad encoding quality?

Comment: I made sure the order was correct. ENCODE_PARAM just specifies the jpeg quality to be 90 instead of the default 95